# CMake command query (add_custom_command)

Tags: c, cmake, embedded

I was using the following command for generating Checksum value, .hex and .bin files.

Unfortunately an error comes in the first.

I'm getting error in generating checksum.

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} --fill; 0xFF;0x0-0x3CFFD;--checksum=__checksum:2,crc16,0x0;0x0-0x3CFFD
               
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} --ihex ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Output/exe/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.elf ${HEX_FILE}
                
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} --bin ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Output/exe/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.elf ${BIN_FILE}
                WORKING_DIRECTORY  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Output/exe
                COMMENT "Building ${HEX_FILE} \nBuilding ${BIN_FILE}")
```

The error pop up as

> ielftool error: Missing separator in command line option (expected ';'): "0xFF"

Can anyone help out here? It will be a great help.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe check for the `VERBATIM` and/or `USE_TERMINAL`  options or use `"<options>"`. (<options> starting at -fill to the end of that line)

Comment: I don't think you want the semicolons.  I think CMake passes the string as it is written to the shell

Comment: `--fill; 0xFF;0x0-0x3CFFD;--checksum=__checksum:2,crc16,0x0;0x0-0x3CFFD` What is going on here? What should that line execute?

Comment: I used the following command now .But now the error is different .                                                                     set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS "--fill 0xFF;0x500-0x3CFFD --checksum __checksum:2,crc16,0x0;0x500-0x3CFFD --place_holder  __checksum,2,.checksum,1 --define_symbol __checksum_begin=0x500 --define_symbol __checksum_end=0xfffb --cpu Cortex-m0+ --warnings_are_errors --remarks --semihosting --config ${LINKER_SCRIPT}")                                      Command line error: Unexpected command line arguments:
   IAR ELF Linker V8.42.1.236/W32 for ARM
            --fill

Comment: I'm trying to fill checksum within the address range      ..I already tried with command line .It works perfectly .Getting error compiling through CMake ..

Comment: Hi, Thanks all . I got the Solution by using the  below command          
add_custom_command(TARGET ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} --fill 0xFF\;0x500-0x3CFFD --checksum __checksum:2,crc16,0x0\;0x500-0x3CFFD "Test.elf" "Test.elf"                                    
                                                                                                                                                Useful link for Future endeavor --https://www.silabs.com/community/software/simplicity-studio/knowledge-base.entry.html/2016/12/12/enabling_checksumus-6elz

Answer (score 0):

I was stucked on the same problem by using ielftool in postBuild via IAR Linux Compiler. At the end I got it running but there are some rules to be considered:

- the ";" separator has to be written in quotation marks "';'" ("slash" works also)
- last arguments of out-file must be wrapped by ""
- spae characters between arguments cause some errors

Example:
/opt/iarsystems/bxarm/arm/bin/ielftool --fill 0xFF';'$FLASH_START-$FLASH_START_HEADER --fill 0xFF';'$FLASH_PROGRAMMCODE_START-$FLASH_PROGRAMMCODE_END --checksum __checksum:4,crc32,0x0';'$FLASH_START-$FLASH_START_HEADER';'$FLASH_PROGRAMMCODE_START-$FLASH_PROGRAMMCODE_END --verbose "$INPUT_FILE" "$INPUT_FILE"

```
                #/opt/iarsystems/bxarm/arm/bin/ielftool --fill 0xFF\;$FLASH_START-$FLASH_START_HEADER --fill 0xFF\;$FLASH_PROGRAMMCODE_START-$FLASH_PROGRAMMCODE_END --checksum __checksum:4,crc32,0x0\;$FLASH_START-$FLASH_START_HEADER\;$FLASH_PROGRAMMCODE_START-$FLASH_PROGRAMMCODE_END --verbose "$INPUT_FILE" "$INPUT_FILE"
```